# What do rock octoroks do to weapons in Tears of the Kingdom?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

From the rumors I've heard, it sounds like rock octoroks can:
a) repair weapons
b) add modifiers to weapons

If this is true, how does this work? What determines what kind of modifier you get?

Comment: Do you mean "Rock Octoroks"? I haven't seen anything about "Fire Octoroks" on the web...

Comment: Huh. I tried dropping my flashing red weapon near a rock octorok, and sure enough, it sucked it up, some sparkly effects played and when it spat it out it wasn't flashing red anymore, and had a +4 attack modifier.

Comment: @TimmyJim Thanks for pointing this out. I fixed this.

Comment: @Showsni I assume that by "flashing red weapon" you mean a badly damaged weapon?

Comment: @User23415 Yes, the kind that flash red on the inventory screen and give the warning message when you pull them out.

Comment: Not a full answer but, from the little bit of experimenting I tried they seem to repair metal weapons (mine was a royal claymore + Frost Talus Heart) but not Zonai (or Wood?). The Zonai longsword I fed it was chucked back still damaged. I know in BOTW the rock octorocks took rusted weapons and spat back the clean versions, so maybe that is why I could only get the metal ones repaired?

Comment: @Showsni that means it has 3 or less durability.

Comment: Looking at it again it seems like they only can be used to repair a weapon once per blood moon (rather than it only working on metal weapons)? I think there is more information out there about how rock octrocs work but I don't have it handy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once per blood moon, each rock octorok can repair a single item. This happens when the octorok inhales a weapon, bow, or shield. The octorok will chew on the item for a little bit, and then will spit it out with full durability and a potentially better modifier. Specifically:

- If the weapon has no modifier, it will get a random white modifier.
- If the weapon has a white modifier, it will be replaced by a random gold modifier.
- If the weapon has a gold modifier, it will be rerolled.

Note that it is possible to reload your save until you get your desired modifier, which is helpful if you are grinding for a pristine +10 Royal Guard's Claymore.